# Is the 1e6 causing me to get a Type Error?

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

oneFileName = listOfFiles[0]

lineNum = 0

listOfLists = []

with open(oneFileName,"rt") as csvfile:
    lineReader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",",quotechar="\"")
    for row in lineReader:
        lineNum = (lineNum + 1)
        if lineNum == 1:
            print("Skipping the header row")
            continue
        symbol = row[0]
        close = row[5]
        prevClose = row[7]
        tradedQty = row[9]
        pctChange = float(float(close)/float(prevClose) - 1)
        oneResultRow = [symbol, pctChange,float(tradedQty)]
        listOfLists.append(oneResultRow)
        print(symbol, "{:,.lf}".format(float(tradedQty/1e6), "M INR", "{:,.lf}".format(pctChange*100), "%"))
    print("Done iterating over the file contents - the file is closed now!")
    print("We have stock info for " + str(len(listOfLists)))

listOfListsSortedByQty = sorted(listOfLists, key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=True)

listOfListsSortedByQty = sorted(listOfLists, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

**I keep getting this error:**

```
print(symbol, "{:,.lf}".format(float(tradedQty/1e6), "M INR", "{:,.lf}".format(pctChange*100), "%"))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the problem is that you put your brackets in the wrong place.

```
    float(tradedQty/1e6)
//        ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^
//        string  float
//  ^^^^^
// too late
```

I'm sure you meant to write:

```
float(tradedQty)/1e6
```

Answer (score 0):

`tradedQty` is a string.  `1e6` is numeric, and is not the problem.

The CSV file is just strings, so you'll want to convert the numeric data to, well, numeric types.  Try `tradedQty = float(row[9])`